# Future of SchemaUpdate?

Tags: nhibernate, schema, nhibernate-3

I read [somewhere](http://216.121.112.228/browse/NH-1442?focusedCommentId=16720&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_16720) that "SchemaUpdate is not recommended in NH2.0.0.". I'm afraid that if this is supported in NHibernate 3 or not? And what's its road map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you read was a suggestion not to use it in 2.0.0 because that release was already improved upon in the trunk. They were just saying, "Hey, don't use the old stuff."

Schema Update has continued to be and remains supported.